# Rose grows with thorns or rose grow with thorns which one is correct?

Tags: grammar

I am an unripe writer but I find problems in writing English quotes due to my grammatical mistakes

Which one is correct:

> Rose **grows** with thorns
>
> Rose **grow** with thorn

Comment: If you mean "rose" as an uncountable entity (like sometimes how "man" is used to mean mankind), you could also say "the rose grows with thorns" with "the" added.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one rose you use: it **grows**, if you have more roses: they **grow**

Answer (score 0):

The subject and verb agree in number.

Roses grow     (plural)

A rose grows   (singular)